# SQL SELECT with LEFT and LEN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I have a PRJ_NAME result of "**Authoriazations - XXXXXX-XXXXXX**", but all I want is "**Authorizations**", so I use this query with complete success.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(LEFT(PRJ_NAME, LEN(PRJ_NAME)-16),'') AS 'Folder Name'
FROM    MHGROUP.PROJECTS 
WHERE   PRJ_ID = '3626747'
```

Now, when I use the following query with a basic join, I can't use this logic within this query.

```
SELECT  m.[DOCNAME], 
        m.[SUBCLASS_ALIAS],
        u.FULLNAME,
        m.[CDATE3] as 'File Date',
        m.[DECLAREWHEN] as 'Declared',
        ISNULL(LEFT(p.PRJ_NAME, LEN(p.PRJ_NAME)-16),'') as 'Folder Name',
        m.ENTRYWHEN
FROM    ([Imanage].[MHGROUP].[DOCMASTER] as m (nolock)
JOIN    [Imanage].[MHGROUP].[DOCUSERS] as u (nolock) on u.USERID = m.OPERATOR), 
        [Imanage].[MHGROUP].[PROJECTS] as p (nolock), 
        [Imanage].[MHGROUP].[PROJECT_ITEMS] as i (nolock)
WHERE   i.ITEMTYPE = 'D' and
        i.ITEM_ID = m.DOCNUM and 
        i.PRJ_ID = p.PRJ_ID
ORDER BY u.FULLNAME, p.PRJ_NAME
```

I get the following error...

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 Invalid length parameter passed to
>   the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I can't seem to think of what could be causing this.  Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is value in `PRJ_NAME` column that is less than 16 characters.

same error seen with below simple query

```
select LEFT('abc', LEN('abc')-16)
```

Check if there is any such name and handle it with case statement

```
case when len(PRJ_NAME) > 16 
     then LEFT(p.PRJ_NAME, LEN(p.PRJ_NAME)-16) 
     ELSE prj_name 
END
```

Comment: why wouldn't the first query fail?  Also, I think he doesn't need `len` at all, just `left(prt_name,14)` or maybe `left(prt_name,len('Authorizations'))`

Comment: @Beth, left(prt_name,len('Authorizations')) will also fail if prj_name is less than 16 that is it doesn't contain Authorizations at all, some bad entry

Comment: right, but he said he used his first query "with complete success."  how can that happen if there's bad (short) data?

Comment: @beth, that worked for the project id 3626747 , it is tested only for one row.

Comment: @RADAR, that worked like a charm.  Thanks. (I seriously sometimes forget to just look outside the darn box).